# mod_proxy protocol handler problems

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I'm trying to forward incoming web traffic to a Plone server on my Ubuntu set-up using the following rules (based on '[Installing Plone with Apache](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/plone-with-apache)'):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

 ProxyRequests Off
 <Proxy *>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
 </Proxy>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:7373/VirtualHostBase/http/mydomain.com:80/plonesite/VirtualHostRoot/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7373/VirtualHostBase/http/mydomain.com:80/plonesite/VirtualHostRoot/
  #ProxyPass / http://localhost:7373/ukpa/
  #ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7373/ukpa/
</VirtualHost>
```

Both variations, however produce and Internal Server Error, that shows in the log as:

> [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was
>   valid for the URL /. If you are using
>   a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure
>   the proxy submodules are included in
>   the configuration using LoadModule.

I can browse locally to the site, via lynx, using the address http://localhost:7373/ukpa/ (hence the commented out attempts to simply forward to that at the bottom).

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try:

```
# cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
# ln -s ../mods-available/proxy.load
# ln -s ../mods-available/proxy_http.load
```

Comment: You'll need to restart apache after doing this step.